# Unable to run dataflow in DataflowRunner mode because of environment issues

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am running dataflow job which reads file and pushes data to cloudsql. Its working in local mode(DirectRunner) but failing in DataflowRunner mode.  I am getting following error

```
I 2021-08-24T10:08:13.866094Z   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 
I 2021-08-24T10:08:13.866142Z    command: /usr/local/bin/python3 /tmp/pip-standalone-pip-_qnajhyd/__env_pip__.zip/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-idcssgqm/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: --no-index --find-links /var/opt/google/dataflow -- 'setuptools>=54.0' 'setuptools_scm[toml]>=5.0' 'wheel>=0.36.2' 'Cython>=0.29.22' 
I 2021-08-24T10:08:13.866202Z        cwd: None 
I 2021-08-24T10:08:13.866213Z   Complete output (15 lines): 
I 2021-08-24T10:08:13.866222Z   Looking in links: /var/opt/google/dataflow 
I 2021-08-24T10:08:13.866232Z   Processing /var/opt/google/dataflow/setuptools-57.4.0.tar.gz 
I 2021-08-24T10:08:13.866244Z     Installing build dependencies: started 
I 2021-08-24T10:08:13.866253Z     Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'error' 
I 2021-08-24T10:08:13.866262Z     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 
I 2021-08-24T10:08:13.866272Z      command: /usr/local/bin/python3 /tmp/pip-standalone-pip-_qnajhyd/__env_pip__.zip/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-x9grztra/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: --no-index --find-links /var/opt/google/dataflow -- wheel 
I 2021-08-24T10:08:13.866290Z          cwd: None 
I 2021-08-24T10:08:13.866305Z     Complete output (3 lines): 
I 2021-08-24T10:08:13.866314Z     Looking in links: /var/opt/google/dataflow 
I 2021-08-24T10:08:13.866324Z     ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement wheel (from versions: none) 
I 2021-08-24T10:08:13.866335Z     ERROR: No matching distribution found for wheel 
I 2021-08-24T10:08:13.866344Z     ---------------------------------------- 
I 2021-08-24T10:08:13.866359Z   WARNING: Discarding file:///var/opt/google/dataflow/setuptools-57.4.0.tar.gz. Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/bin/python3 /tmp/pip-standalone-pip-_qnajhyd/__env_pip__.zip/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-x9grztra/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: --no-index --find-links /var/opt/google/dataflow -- wheel Check the logs for full command output. 
I 2021-08-24T10:08:13.866383Z   ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools>=54.0 (from versions: 57.4.0) 
I 2021-08-24T10:08:13.866394Z   ERROR: No matching distribution found for setuptools>=54.0 
I 2021-08-24T10:08:13.866404Z   ---------------------------------------- 
I 2021-08-24T10:08:13.869072Z WARNING: Discarding file:///var/opt/google/dataflow/pymssql-2.2.2.tar.gz. Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/bin/python3 /tmp/pip-standalone-pip-_qnajhyd/__env_pip__.zip/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-idcssgqm/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: --no-index --find-links /var/opt/google/dataflow -- 'setuptools>=54.0' 'setuptools_scm[toml]>=5.0' 'wheel>=0.36.2' 'Cython>=0.29.22' Check the logs for full command output. 
I 2021-08-24T10:08:13.869405Z ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pymssql (from versions: 2.2.2) 
I 2021-08-24T10:08:13.869475Z ERROR: No matching distribution found for pymssql 
I 2021-08-24T10:08:13.943732Z /usr/local/bin/pip failed with exit status 1 
F 2021-08-24T10:08:13.943818Z Failed to install packages: failed to install requirements: exit status 1 
I 2021-08-24T10:11:13.976686Z [topologymanager] RemoveContainer - Container ID: 6006a3d10b0289d5b69478c1a8189eef02db1fa0af2216bb5e7c57659498009c 
I 2021-08-24T10:11:14.015846Z [topologymanager] RemoveContainer - Container ID: bb14dd1d3a5414c2ea02157ebff7e7ba227337e47ff86216a3f86847e261cdee 
E 2021-08-24T10:11:14.016267Z Error syncing pod 5814435f816ec192ccc2709209670a6a ("dataflow-cloudsql-upload-2021-08-2-08240304-up8o-harness-x0f4_default(5814435f816ec192ccc2709209670a6a)"), skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "python" with CrashLoopBackOff: "back-off 1m20s restarting failed container=python pod=dataflow-cloudsql-upload-2021-08-2-08240304-up8o-harness-x0f4_default(5814435f816ec192ccc2709209670a6a)" 
I 2021-08-24T10:11:25.595721Z [topologymanager] RemoveContainer - Container ID: bb14dd1d3a5414c2ea02157ebff7e7ba227337e47ff86216a3f86847e261cdee 
E 2021-08-24T10:11:25.596300Z Error syncing pod 5814435f816ec192ccc2709209670a6a ("dataflow-cloudsql-upload-2021-08-2-08240304-up8o-harness-x0f4_default(5814435f816ec192ccc2709209670a6a)"), skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "python" with CrashLoopBackOff: "back-off 1m20s restarting failed container=python pod=dataflow-cloudsql-upload-2021-08-2-08240304-up8o-harness-x0f4_default(5814435f816ec192ccc2709209670a6a)" 
I 2021-08-24T10:11:38.592275Z [topologymanager] RemoveContainer - Container ID: bb14dd1d3a5414c2ea02157ebff7e7ba227337e47ff86216a3f86847e261cdee 
E 2021-08-24T10:11:38.592668Z Error syncing pod 5814435f816ec192ccc2709209670a6a ("dataflow-cloudsql-upload-2021-08-2-08240304-up8o-harness-x0f4_default(5814435f816ec192ccc2709209670a6a)"), skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "python" with CrashLoopBackOff: "back-off 1m20s restarting failed container=python pod=dataflow-cloudsql-upload-2021-08-2-08240304-up8o-harness-x0f4_default(5814435f816ec192ccc2709209670a6a)" 
I 2021-08-24T10:11:53.598346Z [topologymanager] RemoveContainer - Container ID: bb14dd1d3a5414c2ea02157ebff7e7ba227337e47ff86216a3f86847e261cdee
```

There are so many SO posts which suggested to see about, conflicts with dependency in requirements and even after trying multiple changes in requirements.txt (trial and error) I am unable to figure out right dependencies. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59576287/why-did-i-encounter-an-error-syncing-pod-with-dataflow-pipeline) and
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65588519/dataflow-fails-due-to-error-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-require) but was unable to debug. Following is my code files

dataflow.py

```
import csv
import datetime
import logging
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io.fileio import MatchFiles, ReadMatches
import argparse
import os
import json
from ldif3 import LDIFParser
import pymssql

from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions, GoogleCloudOptions

logging.basicConfig(level='INFO')

# Change the project_id
project_id = os.getenv('GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT')


def get_db_connection():
    
    mssqlhost = '127.0.0.1'
    mssqluser = 'a'
    mssqlpass = 'b'
    mssqldb = 'usersdb'

    cnx = pymssql.connect(user=mssqluser, password=mssqlpass,
                              host=mssqlhost, database=mssqldb)
    return cnx

class SQLWriteDoFn(beam.DoFn):
    # Max documents to process at a time
    MAX_DOCUMENTS = 200

    def __init__(self, project):
        self._project = project

    def setup(self):
        os.system("wget https://dl.google.com/cloudsql/cloud_sql_proxy.linux.amd64 -O cloud_sql_proxy")
        os.system("chmod +x cloud_sql_proxy")
        os.system(f"./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=mydatabase-database=tcp:0.0.0.0:1433 &")

    def start_bundle(self):
        self._mutations = []
        logging.info("In start_bundle")

    def finish_bundle(self):
        logging.info("In finish_bundle")
        if self._mutations:
            self._flush_batch()

    def process(self, element, *args, **kwargs):
        logging.info("In process")
        self._mutations.append(element)
        if len(self._mutations) > self.MAX_DOCUMENTS:
            self._flush_batch()

    def _flush_batch(self):

        try:
            mssqlconn = get_db_connection()
            print("Connection Established to MS SQL server.")
            cursor = mssqlconn.cursor()
            stmt  = "insert into usersdb.dbo.users_dataflow (uname, password) values (%s,%s)"
            cursor.executemany(stmt, self._mutations)
            mssqlconn.commit()
            mssqlconn.close()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        self._mutations = []


def return_dictionary_element_if_present(dict_entry, element):
    if dict_entry.get(element):
        return dict_entry.get(element)[0]
    return ''

class CreateEntities(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, file):
        parser = LDIFParser(file.open())
        arr=[]
        for dn, entry in parser.parse():
            # dict1 ={}
            dict_entry = dict(entry)
            uname = return_dictionary_element_if_present(dict_entry,'uname')
            userPassword = return_dictionary_element_if_present(dict_entry,'userPassword')
            arr.append(tuple((uname,userPassword)))
        return arr


     


def dataflow(pipeline_options):
    print("starting")
    options = GoogleCloudOptions.from_dictionary(pipeline_options)
    with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
        (p | 'Reading data from GCS' >> MatchFiles(file_pattern="gs://my_bucket_name/*.ldiff")
           | 'file match' >> ReadMatches()
           | 'Create entities' >> beam.ParDo(CreateEntities())
#           | 'print to screen' >> beam.Map(print)
           | 'Write to CloudSQL' >> beam.ParDo(SQLWriteDoFn(pipeline_options['project']))
         )


if __name__ == '__main__':

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='dataflow options for ldif to sql')
    parser.add_argument('--project', help='Project ID',
                        default=f'{project_id}')
    parser.add_argument('--region', help='region', default='us-central1')
    parser.add_argument('--runner', help='Runner', default='DirectRunner')
    parser.add_argument('--staging_location',
                        default=f'gs://{project_id}/staging')
    parser.add_argument('--temp_location',
                        default=f'gs://{project_id}/tmp')


    args = parser.parse_args()
    JOB_NAME = 'cloudsql-upload-{}'.format(
        datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S'))
    pipeline_options = {
        'project': args.project,
        'staging_location': args.staging_location,
        'runner': args.runner,
        'job_name': JOB_NAME,
        'temp_location': args.temp_location,
        'save_main_session': True,
        'requirements_file': 'requirements.txt',
        'region': args.region,
        'machine_type': 'n1-standard-8'
    }
    dataflow(pipeline_options)
```

requirements.txt

```
ldif3
pymssql
apache-beam[gcp]==2.31.0
```

Execution way

```
python3 dataflow.py --runner=DataflowRunner
```

Any help is really appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Edit1:
I have done multiple trial and error and finally changed my requirements file as following

```
setuptools==57.4.0
wheel==0.37.0
setuptools_scm[toml]==6.0.1
Cython==0.29.24
ldif3
apache-beam[gcp]==2.31.0
```

But iam getting only following error now.

```
ERROR: pymssql-2.2.2-cp36-cp36m-manylinux_2_12_i686.manylinux2010_i686.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

The way iam running now is

```
python3 dataflow.py --runner=DataflowRunner --requirements_file=requirements.txt --extra_package=pymssql-2.2.2-cp36-cp36m-manylinux_2_12_i686.manylinux2010_i686.whl
```

Answer (score 0):

> When you run your pipeline locally, the packages that your pipeline
> depends on are available because they are installed on your local
> machine. However, when you want to run your pipeline remotely, you
> must make sure these dependencies are available on the remote
> machines.

In your execution way I see that you don't specify the requirements.txt:
so you need to start by adding `--requirements_file requirements.txt`

Ref: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i do have it in pipeline_options as below 'requirements_file': 'requirements.txt'
So this does not do what you are specifying via command line? I can try the way you mentioned but just curious if the way i have given works or not

Answer (score 0):

The error

> is not a supported wheel on this platform

is probably due to trying to use a Python 3.6 wheel with a Beam pipeline that uses a different Python version. Can you try to use a wheel that matches the Python version your Beam pipeline is run with ?